# Change Image cut

Tags: 7, media

i have this problem: i need a image (the image has its own image-field) inside a node with a specific size and cut. the size is always fixed for example at 300x300px. now i want the user choose the cut of the image, so he can drag the image inside the boundary box like facebook does with its thumbnail profile pictures.
this user choosen cut should be visible as thumbnail on the site.

i know there is such a module which can create a thumbnail for including into text but i dont know how its called and if its works with imagecache...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [Image javascript crop](http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop):

> This module makes an Imagecache 2 (D6) or Styles (D7) 'javascript
>   crop' toolbox action available for use with several modules...

or [Imagefield Crop](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop)

> imagefield_crop provides a widget for cropping an image after upload.

Comment: oh yeah this is exactly what i was looking for! thank you very very much!